# Update minor version in package.json

Tags: npm

I have node.js project with next package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my_proj",
  "version": "1.2.3",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

what I need, is to update version of project to 1.3.0 via npm.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-your-published-package-version-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In semantic versioning, the first digits is the major version, the second the minor version, and the third, patches.

You want the minor version to be incremented so use `npm version minor`:

```
$ npm version minor
```